# Adding padding is working differently in Chrome and Firefox than it is in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, navbar

## What I Am Making

On my site, the navigation bar does not start at the top of the page, instead it is a little way down the page, under the header/banner. When the user scrolls down past the nav bar, I change it's position to fixed so that it now stays visible at the top of the page as they scroll through the rest of the content.

I want this to look really seamless, so, when the navbar becomes fixed, I add some padding to the main content to stop it from jumping up into the space where the navbar was. I'm doing all this in my javascript, using jQuery to add classes ands styles to particular elements.

---

## The Problem

In Safari, my code is working perfectly! The problem I have is that on Chrome and Firefox it seems like I need to add more padding than I do on Safari. On Chrome and Firefox the content is still jumping up slightly after the navbar becomes fixed. Whilst trying different values, I discovered that on those browsers, I need exactly 20 extra padding to make the transition seamless, but then the content jumps up too far on Safari!

Why is this extra padding needed on some browsers but not Safari?

If anyone can help I would be truly grateful because this is really bugging me! I have no idea why this is behaving differently in different browsers.

Here is a code snippet. I've tried to minimise the amount of code needed to recreate the issue but the CSS is a bit verbose because I thought I'd better include it all in case there's something there that is causing the issue.

## ----- EDIT -----

OK I discovered that the element which is causing the problem is my `.navbar-button` which I didn't include in my original snippet. I have added it in now. This is the thing which is behaving differently in different browsers.

I had to add margin to this element because it was not positioning correctly in Chrome or Firefox without it, whereas in Safari it was positioned just fine.

This extra margin is what is causing the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $navBar = $(".navbar");

  $(window).scroll(handleScroll);

  function handleScroll() {
    fixNavbarToTopIfNecessary();
  }

  function fixNavbarToTopIfNecessary() {
    var bannerHeight = $("#banner").outerHeight();

    //When user scrolled past the initial position of the navbar
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > bannerHeight) {

      $navBar.addClass("navbar-fixed");
      $("#content").css("padding-top", $navBar.outerHeight() + "px"); // So that the content doesn't jump underneath the fixed nav.
    } else {
      $navBar.removeClass("navbar-fixed");
      $("#content").removeAttr("style");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #888;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* Prevent font scaling in landscape while allowing user zoom */
}
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
p,
img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row::before,
.row::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row::after {
  clear: both;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.column {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.s12 {
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.container {
  width: 970px;
}
#banner {
  background-color: #794f29;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 150px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.banner-intro {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.banner-intro-heading {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffecb0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.banner-intro-lead {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #a16fff;
  border: 1px solid #8748ff;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #a16fff;
  color: white;
  border-color: #8748ff;
}
.banner-intro-button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.navbar {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  /* this stopped the font weight from changing when the navbar is fixed */
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 236, 176, 0.97);
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  z-index: 99;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  /* hack to make sure the navbar is repainted when it's set to a fixed-navbar on iOS */
}
.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Merienda", cursive;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
}
.navbar-items {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #794f29;
  transition: .3s;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.navbar-button {
    background-color: #a16fff;
    border-color: #8748ff;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    box-shadow: -2px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.featured {
  text-align: center;
}
.featured-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: #ccaa8c;
}
.featured-subtitle {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: #666;
}
.featured .lead {
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <section id="banner">
    <div class="banner-intro">
      <h1 class="banner-intro-heading">Grand Title!</h1>
      <p class="banner-intro-lead">Lorem ipsum lorum ipsum sausage rat cake mammoth hair.</p>
      <a class="btn banner-intro-button" href="#">Call to Action</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <nav class="navbar"> <!-- This is what I add the navbar-fixed class to -->
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      <div class="navbar-items">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link4</a>
            
                <li><a class="btn navbar-button" href="#">Button</a></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<main id="content"> <!-- This is what I add the padding to -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column s12">
        <section class="featured">
          <h2 class="featured-title">Featured Title</h2>
          <h3 class="featured-subtitle">Featured Subtitle</h3>
          <p class="lead">Lots of info about said feature that rambles on forever and forever.</p>
          <p class="lead">Even more info blablablablalblablabla.</p>
        </section>

      </div>
      <div class="column s12">
        <section class="featured">
          <h2 class="featured-title">Featured Title</h2>
          <h3 class="featured-subtitle">Featured Subtitle</h3>
          <p class="lead">Lots of info about said feature that rambles on forever and forever.</p>
          <p class="lead">Even more info blablablablalblablabla.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class="column s12">
        <section class="featured">
          <h2 class="featured-title">Featured Title</h2>
          <h3 class="featured-subtitle">Featured Subtitle</h3>
          <p class="lead">Lots of info about said feature that rambles on forever and forever.</p>
          <p class="lead">Even more info blablablablalblablabla.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class="column s12">
        <section class="featured">
          <h2 class="featured-title">Featured Title</h2>
          <h3 class="featured-subtitle">Featured Subtitle</h3>
          <p class="lead">Lots of info about said feature that rambles on forever and forever.</p>
          <p class="lead">Even more info blablablablalblablabla.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: i can't see that jump when scroll down the page in chrome! where do you set that padding to be different in safari and chrome?

Comment: Do you know what. You are absolutely right. There is something else that I haven't included in the snippet that is affecting it.

Comment: I will edit my snippet and add back in more of my original code to see what's causing it.

Comment: @saeedserpooshan OK that took ages but it helped me locate the the exact element that is causing the problem. Thanks for pointing out that it was actually fine before. You should be able to see the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solution for your problem (use each of them is enough).

**Method 1)** Change `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of `.navbar-button` to `0` (to prevent vertical margin collapsing...) , and use `vertical-align: middle;` for center it vertically:

```
.navbar-button {
  background-color: #a16fff;
  border-color: #8748ff;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0 15px; /* *** margin top & bottom are changed to zero! */
  vertical-align: middle; /* *** this is new! */
  line-height: normal;
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

---

**Method 2)** remove `display: inline-block` from `.btn` class:

```
.btn {
  background-color: #a16fff;
  border: 1px solid #8748ff;
  color: #fff;
  /* display: inline-block; */ /* *** this is removed! */
  ...
}
```

it is obvious that if you don't want to change default styles of `.btn`, you can add `display: block` to your navbar button manually as an inline style (`style="display: block;"`) or using a new css class (eg: .block) for it.

```
<li>
  <a class="btn navbar-button" href="#" style="display: block;">Button</a>
</li>
```

Comment: The `vertical-align: middle` worked a treat! Thanks for your help! :)